# How to create custom text forms in admin panel and show them on my page (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, admin, custom-post-type, submenu

**Introduction:**
At this moment I'm creating my first custom Wordpress theme. Now I succesfully created a HTML/CSS template and converted this to fit wordpress (including header.php, index.php, footer.php, functions.php, sidebar.php and page.php).

**Case/Problem definition:**
At my homepage (index.php), I included several div's filled with text (pure HTML and CSS). Now I want to be able to manually change this text from an admin panel in my Wordpress Back-end. I already made an extra sub-menu page in the admin panel. This page is completely blank at this moment.

**In Short:**
How to fill in a text form in my Wordpress admin panel and echo this out on a certain page (front-end).

**Extra**
Since I'm new to Wordpress, PHP and creating your own themes I'm not sure how to do this or how to search for tutorials online (I don't know the correct terminology to search).

Thanks for all the tips and advice already!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `functions.php` add the following code that is highlighted.  This will add a twitterid.  So anywhere in your custom theme you can call the value of the custom admin page:

add menu item:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_global_custom_options');
```

Assign the custom function which will create a form.

```
function add_global_custom_options()  
{  
    add_options_page('Global Custom Options', 'Global Custom Options', 'manage_options', 'functions','global_custom_options');  
}
```

Create a Function Which Generates the Form:

```
<?php
function global_custom_options()
{
?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Global Custom Options</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options') ?>
            <p><strong>Twitter ID:</strong><br />
                <input type="text" name="twitterid" size="45" value="<?php echo get_option('twitterid'); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Store Options" /></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
            <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="twitterid" />
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

View your admin page. You will find a new link in your Admin Menu called “Global Custom Options”.  Just enter your values in that form and you are good to go for using those values in your theme files like “get_option(‘twitterid’)”.  So, in your index.php or any other theme file, you can do something like

```
<?php echo get_option('twitterid') ?>
```

and it will print whatever value is in the textbox on admin page.

Here is a link to the [tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/quick-tip-create-a-wordpress-global-options-page/) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpfull respons Topher Ellis!

Just for the record and for the people that are completely new with PHP and wordpress, I echo'd the function so it was actually shown at the front-page. Written as following:

<?php echo get_option('twitterid') ?>

Comment: Ah!  good catch, there does need to be an echo in there.  I will edit my solution.

Comment: I have just started learning wordpress and I am not able to get my head around things. What is the options.php file ? Should I be writing it ? If so , what needs to go into that page as far as this example is concerned ? Can anyone please help me out here.Thanks already.

Comment: @harsha You can use the `options.php` file to create custom admin option panels.  In the example above, it accomplishes task by using the `functions.php` file. Additional Documentation [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages)

Comment: Use the `<?php @submit_button(); ?>` It will show the proper Save Button for the form. WP will handle the rest