# Wordpress - How to integrate the Editor in a custom Admin Panel

Tags: wordpress, editor, admin

I´ve read this article: [How to create custom text forms in admin panel and show them on my page (Wordpress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457766/how-to-create-custom-text-forms-in-admin-panel-and-show-them-on-my-page-wordpre/20458104#20458104?newreg=3905bed501ae4e5da65f3d15b51e3e94)

Everything works fine, but I need the Editor to do more formating on the Text. Is there an easy Way to integrate?

Thanx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to do this? If you update your question to include the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and information about what you have tried so far, so might be able to offer more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wp_editor();](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_editor/) instead of a text area